# How declare list on int

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS SQL I need to declare list of int to use it in `IN` clause.
Like this:

```
DECLARE @DATE AS DATE = '01.01.2018'
SELECT * FROM tank_state WHERE dt = @DATE AND tankId IN (14,15)
```

This work fine. Nice.

Here with  `DECLARE`:

```
DECLARE @DATE AS DATE = '01.01.2018'
DECLARE @listOfIDs int = 14,15
SELECT * FROM tank_state WHERE dt = @DATE AND tankId IN (@listOfIDs)
```

But I get error:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near '15'.
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 102
Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@listOfIDs".
SQLState:  S1000
ErrorCode: 137
```

Answer (score 7):

That is incorrect syntax. You can't put two ints into a variable and 14,15 will fail to convert to an int.

An option is to put those values into a table:

```
DECLARE @ints TABLE (val INT)
INSERT INTO @ints (val)
VALUES 
(14),
(15)

SELECT * FROM tank_state WHERE dt = @DATE AND tankId IN (SELECT val FROM @ints)
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE = '2018-01-01';
DECLARE @listOfIDs varchar(max) = '14,15';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT *
FROM tank_state
WHERE dt = @DATE AND tankId IN (@listOfIDs)';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@listOfIds', @listOfIds);

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@date date', @date = date;
```

However, a more accepted method is to split the list using a function, such as `string_split()` (available in SQL Server 2016 and onward)

```
SELECT *
FROM tank_state
WHERE dt = @DATE AND tankId IN (SELECT * FROM string_split(@listOfIDs, ','))';
```